# If $b\in C^1(E, \mathbb{R})$ and $b'$ is compact, then $b$ is weakly continuous — a reference request

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

While reading the well known book *Minimax Methods in Critical Point Theory with Applications to Differential Equations* by Paul Rabinowitz, in the proof of a generalisation of the Mountain Pass Theorem (Theorem 5.29 in the book), I encountered the following abstract result:

> Let $E$ be a real Hilbert space and consider $b\in C^1(E, \mathbb{R}$) such that $b'$ is compact. Then, $b$ is weakly continuous, i.e. if $(u_n)_n\subseteq E$ converges weakly to $u\in E$, then $b(u_n)\to b(u)$ as $n\to \infty$.

The reference for this result given in the book is

> M. A. Krasnoselski, *Topological methods in the theory of nonlinear integral
> equations*, Macmillan, New York, 1964.

However, even if this is a well renowned book in the field of nonlinear analysis, I do not have access to it. Does anyone know a modern reference for this result? The proof looks nontrivial to me, at least I do not know how to approach it.

EDIT: The fact that $b'$ is compact means that if $A\subseteq E$ is bounded, then the closure of $b'(A)$ is compact. Of course, $b'$ denotes the mapping $x\mapsto b'(x)$, i.e. $b'$ associates with each $x\in E$ the Frechet derivative of $b$ at $x$, which we denote by $b'(x)\in E^{*}$.

Comment: What do you mean by "$b'$ is compact"?

Comment: @IosifPinelis Thank you, now I realise that this notion may be a bit vague. Does my edit clarify this?

Comment: Maybe there's a typo... since even after the edit you've not explained how $b'$ is related to $b$... ?

Comment: @paulgarrett $b'$ associates with each $x\in E$ the Frechet derivative of $b$ at $x$, which we denote by $b'(x)$. I have just added this in my edit, is the notation clear now?

Comment: Ah! Thanks! That certainly was a possibility, but it was hard to guess for sure. :) Sometimes "prime" has some sort of duality sense... :)

Comment: @IosifPinelis sorry, I have just read your post, I had a very long day. I accepted your answer, it fully solved my problem. I didn't expect this to be so straightforward, but I am really grateful for your answer, now I understand how this is proved. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To obtain a contradiction, suppose that $b(u_n)\not\to b(u)$. Passing to a subsequence, without loss of generality (wlog) we have $|b(u_n)-b(u)|\ge c$ for some real $c>0$ and all $n$.

By the mean value theorem, $b(u_n)-b(u)=b'(v_n)(u_n-u)$ for all $n$ and some $v_n$ on the straight line segment from $u$ to $u_n$.

Since the sequence $(u_n)$ is weakly convergent, it is [bounded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_convergence_(Hilbert_space)#Properties). So, recalling that $b'$ is compact and passing to a subsequence, wlog we have  $b'(v_n)\to B$ for some $B\in E^*$. Also, $B(u_n-u)\to0$, since $u_n\to u$ weakly. Also, $\|b'(v_n)-B\|\,\|u_n-u\|\to0$, since $b'(v_n)\to B$ and the sequence $(u_n)$ is bounded.
So,
$$|b(u_n)-b(u)|=|b'(v_n)(u_n-u)|\le\|b'(v_n)-B\|\,\|u_n-u\|+|B(u_n-u)|\to0+0=0,$$
which contradicts the condition that $|b(u_n)-b(u)|\ge c$ for some real $c>0$ and all $n$. $\quad\Box$